# Pytest - Collected 0 items, no Test Ran

Tags: python, flask, pytest

In root directory but pytest not running tests regardless of what command is run (py.test, pytest, python3 -m pytest...)

Based on other posts here, I have followed all of this advice:

- Verify that all files with test cases start with 'test_' word.
- Verify that all test cases names also start with 'test_' word.
- Verify that you have created pytest.ini file in the root directory
- Verify that you have **init**.py file in all directories/sub-directories of the project

File directory:

```
.
├── Procfile
├── __pycache__
├── config.py
├── learning_flashcards
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── __pycache__
│   │   ├── __init__.cpython-36.pyc
│   │   ├── app.cpython-36.pyc
│   │   ├── models.cpython-36.pyc
│   │   └── views.cpython-36.pyc
│   ├── app.py
│   ├── db.py
│   ├── models.py
│   ├── static
│   │   └── style.css
│   ├── templates
│   └── views.py
├── learning_flashcards.egg-info
│   ├── PKG-INFO
│   ├── SOURCES.txt
│   ├── dependency_links.txt
│   ├── requires.txt
│   └── top_level.txt
├── manage.py
├── migrations
│   ├── README
│   ├── alembic.ini
│   ├── env.py
│   ├── script.py.mako
│   └── versions
├── pytest.ini
├── requirements
│   ├── common.txt
│   ├── dev.txt
│   └── runtime.txt
├── requirements.txt
├── setup.py
├── tests
│   ├── [pytest]
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── __pycache__
│   │   ├── __init__.cpython-36.pyc
│   │   ├── conftest.cpython-36-pytest-5.4.3.pyc
│   │   ├── test_data.cpython-36-pytest-5.4.3.pyc
│   │   └── test_site.cpython-36-pytest-5.4.3.pyc
│   ├── conftest.py
│   ├── test_data.py
│   └── test_site.py
└── venv
```

Test file test_site.py:

```
import pytest

from learning_flashcards.app import create_app

@pytest.fixture(autouse=True)
def test_site(app):
    assert app.get(url_for('/')).status_code == 200
```

Contest.py:

```
import pytest

from learning_flashcards.app import create_app

@pytest.fixture
def app():
    app = create_app()
    return app
```

pytest.ini:

```
[pytest]
minversion = 5.4.3
testpath = tests
```

Have never used pytest before so this could be something wrong with my approach.

Comment: Do you have an acual test in test_data/test_site or just fixtures? Fixtures are no tests.

Comment: I think the `fixture` decorator on `test_site` is there by mistake - this should be the actual test.

Comment: I beliive this is the test: def test_site(app):
    assert app.get(url_for('/')).status_code == 200

Comment: removing the fixture decorator worked. also had to remove 'url_for('/')' and just go with ('/'). Thx

Answer (score 2):

It should be `conftest.py`, not `contest.py`.